# Can't delete Anchorfree HSS VPN Adapter created by Hotspot Shield

Tags: windows-10, vpn, network-adapter, hotspot-shield

After uninstalling Hotspot Shield, it's adapter "Anchorfree HSS VPN Adapter" didn't get deleted. And the delete option is grayed and unclickable so I am unable to manually delete it. Although it's not causing any problem, I would still like to delete it. Is there any way I can?

Edit : I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the driver from Device Manager> Network Adapter > Right click on the HSS [VPN](https://switchvpn.net) Adapter and Uninstall, Or you can boot up in safe mode and uninstall it.